# How to print two word which should align left and right in the same line

Tags: docx4j

How can i create a line which has left and right alignment of two text in the same paragraph.
I tried by adding some properties but not working.
[image]
Thanks.

Comment: tabs and tab alignment: http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/tabs.html